# Root View Controller error in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I wrote this code for my application but when I launch the application, I get this message:

`Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`

Here is the code:

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
_tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
ListViewController *listViewController = [[ListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
listViewController.title = @"Lista";
listViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list.jpg"];
InsertViewController *insertViewController = [[InsertViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
insertViewController.title = @"Inserimento";
insertViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.jpg"];
[controllers addObject:insertViewController];
[controllers addObject:listViewController];
_tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

I have try to add this:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

But when I launch the application is all white and the error does not appear.

This is my `appdelegate.m` an I have import header file and write in `appdelegate.h` this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
UITabBarController *_tabBarController
}
```

Comment: do you use story boards?

Comment: why are you not setting rootviewcontroller as tabBarController?

Comment: Do you make you window visible somewhere ? `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` should be called before returning from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: Yeah i make my winwows visible, how do i put tabBarController as rootviewcontroller??

Answer (score 0):

in your AppDelegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

                NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
                _tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
                ListViewController *listViewController = [[ListViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
                listViewController.title = @"Lista";
                listViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"list.jpg"];
                InsertViewController *insertViewController = [[InsertViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
                insertViewController.title = @"Inserimento";
                insertViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.jpg"];
                [controllers addObject:insertViewController];
                [controllers addObject:listViewController];
                _tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
                self.window.rootViewController = _tabBarController;

                [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `tabBarController` as the `rootViewController` of the `UIWindow`. To do this, inside your `AppDelegate.m` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, before the line `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` you need to do add `self.window.rootViewController = _tabBarController;`
Hope this helps.